# Join 3 tables; select from third table row which contains specific string by latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 tables wherein I need to search for this specific string '%sell back%' from the 3rd table and get the **latest** entry from that table, the 3 tables are as follows:

Table#1: Customer

```
|---------------|---------------|
|  Customer ID  | CustomerName  |
|---------------|---------------|
|    1234       | Johnathan     |
---------------------------------
```

Table#2: Problem

```
|---------------|---------------|----------------------|---------------|
|  Problem ID   | CustomerID    | Problem Description  | Date Reported |
|---------------|---------------|----------------------|---------------|
|    3203494    | 1234          | Needs Appointment    | 2019-08-01    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    3178766    | 1234          | Sell Back Customer   | 2019-08-12    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table#3: Problem Event

```
|---------------|---------------|----------------------|---------------|
|ProblemEventID | Problem ID    | Event Reason         | Event Date    |
|---------------|---------------|----------------------|---------------|
|    1926144    | 3178766       | Reported             | 2019-08-12    | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2022750    | 3178766       | sell back            | 2019-08-13    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2022751    | 3178766       | Accepted as sell back| 2019-08-26    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2022899    | 3178766       | Finalized            | 2019-08-31    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The result that I am looking for is as follows:

```
|---------------|---------------|------------|-----------------------|------------|
|  Customer ID  | CustomerName  | Problem Id | Event Reason          | Event Date |
|---------------|---------------|------------|-----------------------|------------|
|    1234       | Johnathan     | 3178766    | Accepted as sell back | 2019-08-26 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------|------------|
```

Your help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: In your sample data only one row matches.  So I don't see the need for the most recent of anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the latest "sell back" event across the whole table, then you can join, order by and limit:

```
select top (1)
    c.customer_id, 
    c.customer_name
    p.problem_id,
    pe.event_reason,
    pe.event_date
from customer c
inner join problem p on p.customer_id = c.customer_id
inner join problem_event pe on pe.problem_id = p.problem_id
where pe.event_reason like '%sell back%'
order by pe.event_date
```

There are other ways to understand your question. Say you want the latest "sell back" event *per customer*, then it is a *greatest-n-per-group* problem. You can use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select
        c.customer_id, 
        c.customer_name
        p.problem_id,
        pe.event_reason,
        pe.event_date,
        row_number() over(partition by c.customer_id order by pe.event_date desc) rn
    from customer c
    inner join problem p on p.customer_id = c.customer_id
    inner join problem_event pe on pe.problem_id = p.problem_id
    where pe.event_reason like '%sell back%'
) t
where rn = 1
order by c.customer_id
```

The exercise of returning the latest "sell back" event *per problem*, which is the last possible interpretation of your question, is left to the reader!

Comment: op seems new, maybe optemize your query to not join on the whole table with sub quries

Comment: @Steve: in the second query this would not optimize anything. That would only make sense in the third option (the last sell back *per problem*), which I did not expand.

Comment: What i mean is to have sub select for the joined tables, and if that&#39;s messy to make use of CTE, so that the join is on a smaller subset of data.

Comment: @GMB Thank you very much the second query was exactly what I was looking for and it seems to be pulling the correct information, and yes I need this data across multiple customers.

I will go through the results and report back if this is the silver bullet?

Thanks for your quick response and help, much appreciated!